# Aura:Id of dynamically created compontns cannot be accessed

Tags: lightning-aura-components, dynamic, aura-id

Below is my code to create the component dynamically - The component is "ui:inputselect"

```
$A.createComponent(
            RecoveryLineItem.Attributes[i].name,{
                "class" : "slds-input ",
                "aura:id" : 'ExampleId',
                "label" : RecoveryLineItem.Attributes[i].label,
                "multiple" : RecoveryLineItem.Attributes[i].multiple
            }, ....
```

..

```
console.log(component.find('ExampleId').get("v.value"))
```

Or `console.log(component.find('ExampleId'))` 
is Giving as 'Undefined"

How to access the aura:id of the dynamically created components?

Comment: can you please provide more code, i think you are missing ui:inputselect in your code.

Comment: Have you figure out the solutions? I tried Junaid's but it doesn't work for me. Cheers

Answer (score 9):

Sorry can't comment yet.

But i have the same problem when using cmp.find() to get a dynamically created component the return value is always undefined.

I even tried it with the code provided in the documentation(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm).

```
<!--c:createComponent-->
<aura:component>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <p aura:id="test">Dynamically created button</p>
    {!v.body}
</aura:component>


/*createComponentController.js*/
({
    doInit : function(cmp) {
        $A.createComponent(
            "ui:button",
            {
                "aura:id": "findableAuraId",
                "label": "Press Me",
                "press": cmp.getReference("c.handlePress")
            },
            function(newButton, status, errorMessage){
                //Add the new button to the body array
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    var body = cmp.get("v.body");
                    body.push(newButton);
                    cmp.set("v.body", body);
                }
                else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                    console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                    // Show offline error
                }
                else if (status === "ERROR") {
                    console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                    // Show error message
                }
            }
        );
    },

    handlePress : function(cmp) {
        console.log("button pressed");
        console.log(cmp.find("findableAuraId"));
    }
})
```

The first console log works, the second one returns 'undefined'

A possible workaround : cmp.find({ instancesOf : "auradocs:sampleComponent" }) which returns an array of all "auradocs:sampleComponent"

```
handlePress : function(cmp) {
    var button = cmp.find({ instancesOf : "ui:button" })[0];
    button.set("v.label", "test");
}
```

Comment: I just tried that myself and can confirm cmp.find(”findableAuraId”) returns undefined on dynamically created cmp. cmp.find('myId') works without problems on a generically created component.

Comment: Just tried this, and the second log returned the component.

Answer (score 7):

I believe this issue is related to [Dynamically created component with aura:id, set as a Facet inside a parent component, is not found when calling find() and passing in aura:id](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148634/dynamically-created-component-with-auraid-set-as-a-facet-inside-a-parent-compo/148845#148845)

Have a look at the answer from Trevor Bliss

Comment: Currently the answer provided in the above post is the easiest workaround - `component.get("v.*attributeName*").get("v.value");`

Answer (score 3):

YOu have to specify the type of component as "ui:inputselect"

```
$A.createComponent(
        "ui:inputselect",
        {
            "class" : "slds-input ",
            "aura:id" : 'ExampleId',
            "label" : RecoveryLineItem.Attributes[i].label,
            "multiple" : RecoveryLineItem.Attributes[i].multiple
        },
        function(status, errorMessage){
            //Add the new button to the body array
            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                //some code.
            }
            else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
               //some code.
            }
            else if (status === "ERROR") {
                //some code.
            }
        }
 );
```

Answer (score 3):

This Bug has been resolved with Spring 18 release:
[Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_lc_find_dynamic_cmp.htm?edition=&impact=)

Answer (score -1):

Posting it again as the issue still persists..

To get the value from a dynamically created component, use :

```
var value = component.get("v.*attributeName*").get("v.value");// for type="Aura.Component"
```

OR

```
var value = component.get("v.*attributeName*")[0].get("v.value"); // for type="Aura.Component[]"
```

For more information, please do checkout [this link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148634/dynamically-created-component-with-auraid-set-as-a-facet-inside-a-parent-compo/164311#164311)

The above answer is based on one of [techbisinessman's](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/8359/techbusinessman) answers.All credits go to him.